# Using python dictionaries

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm new to python and love the idea of the dictionary, but I'm not sure how to use it in this case.  I want to set the serial object parameters all at once and not one at at a time like I've done below.  How can I do that by setting the iso_com1 serial object equal to all the values in the ISOSerialPort section of my config file all at once?  There are get and apply serial functions that take a dictionary, but I'm still not sure of the syntax.  Thanks.

```
import sys, os
import serial
import ConfigParser

pipeout = os.open('USB0Serial', os.O_WRONLY)

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read("serial.config")

iso_com1 = serial.Serial()

iso_com1.port = config.get('ISOSerialPort1', 'port')
iso_com1.baudrate = config.get('ISOSerialPort1', 'baudrate')
iso_com1.open()

while 1:
        line =  iso_com1.readline()
        os.write(pipeout, line)
```

The config file looks like this:

```
[ISOSerialPort1]
port = /dev/ttyUSB0
baudrate = 9600
bytesize = EIGHTBITS
parity = PARITY_NONE
stopbits = STOPBITS_ONE
timeout = 0
xonxoff = NONE
rtscts = FALSE
dsrdtr = FALSE
write_timeout = 0
inter_byte_timeout = NONE
```

Comment: Note that unless you're using a *really* old version of Python, `while True:` is more idiomatic.

Comment: Does `serial.Serial(**dict(config.items('ISOSerialPort1')))` work? If so, I'll add that as an answer with explanation.

Comment: I haven't tried your solution yet, but I have a more basic problem I think.  Configparser stores all values as strings.  So I have to convert the values back to int, boolean etc before assigned them to the serial object.  Can that be done using the shorthand method I'm trying? If they are numbers like baud rate etc they work, but I get this error for bytesize so what kind of value is bytesize?:

iso_com1.bytesize = config.get('ISOSerialPort1', 'bytesize')

gives this error:

raise ValueError("Not a valid byte size: %r" % (bytesize,))
ValueError: Not a valid byte size: 'EIGHTBITS'

Comment: Ah... right, no that wouldn't work. You pretty much have to use the `.getint` etc. methods of config.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
iso_com1.apply_settings(dict(config.items('ISOSerialPort1')))
```

to read all the parameters in the config file. But you should be aware that only supported keys should be in this section and they should be in the right order.

Comment: That seems like it would work except that dict(config.items('ISOSerialPort1')) returns the items in a different order then they are in the config file.

So I experimented with print config.items('ISOSerialPort1') which prints the items in square brackets in the correct order but printing with the dict modifier produces output in curly braces in the wrong order.  Sorry can't cut and paste from the pi terminal at the moment.  Whats happening with dict?  Thanks.

Comment: Oh yes sorry I missed that. A behaviour of dict which isnt that expected but common. Dict has no order but you can use the OrderedDict from the collections package. This should behave as expected.